# Angular 2: Access one components property in another component

Tags: components, angular2-forms

I have a component A (ButtonViewComponent) which looks like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button-view',
  template: `

      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" /><br/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"
                    (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                    (click)="uploader.clearQueue()" [disabled]="!uploader.queue.length">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
          </button>

        <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-bottom: 40px">
          <table class="table">
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
          <div>
              <div>
                  Queue progress:
                  <div class="progress" style="">
                      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>  
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   `,
   styleUrls: ['./category-items.component.scss']
})


export class ButtonViewComponent implements ViewCell, OnInit {

  imagename: any;

 //public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url:'http://localhost:5000/upload'});
 public uploader:FileUploader;

  constructor(){
    this.uploader = new FileUploader({url:'http://localhost:5000/upload'});
    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (fileItem) => {
            fileItem.withCredentials = false;
            this.imagename= fileItem.file.name;

        };
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    //this.renderValue = this.value.toString().toUpperCase();
  }

  onClick() {
    this.create.emit(this.rowData);

  }
}
```

Where console.log(fileItem.file.name);  gives me the uploaded filename.

now i need to access this fileItem.file.name property in another component B (CategoryItemsComponent) which is in the same component file.

**My Component B looks like:**

```
   @Component({
      selector: 'app-category-items',
      templateUrl: './category-items.component.html',
      inputs: ['imagename'],
      styleUrls: ['./category-items.component.scss']
    })

export class CategoryItemsComponent implements OnInit {

    category: String;
    product: String;
    categoryid: String;
    public categories: Array<any> = [];
    public selectedObject: any;
   //public uploader:FileUploader;
    //TRIED LIKE THIS
   //public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url:'http://localhost:5000/upload'});

  source: LocalDataSource;

 constructor(private productService: ProductService,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private router: Router,
   ) {
    this.source = new LocalDataSource();

  }

  onSaveConfirm(event) {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to save?')) {
     // var prodId = event.newData['_id']
  console.log(event)
  let id = event.newData['_id'];


   let image= new ButtonViewComponent();

 console.log(image.imagename)   //GIVES UNDEFINED


  this.productService.productUpdate(id, event.newData).then(data => {
    this.flashMessage.show('Product(s) updated successfully', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
    this.router.navigate(['/category-items']);
  }, (err) => {
    this.flashMessage.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
    console.log(err);
  });

 event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
} else {
  event.confirm.reject();
}

}
```

**category-items.component.html**

To fetch the table i m using ng2-smart table

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="view_update_items_settings" [source]="source" (createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event)" (editConfirm)="onSaveConfirm($event)"  (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)" class="table table-hover table-striped"></ng2-smart-table>
```

I need to get the **image.imagename** property inside the **event.newData** property

Comment: in my case there are no services and i belv @Input is used to pass data to components...i need to pass the objects properties across another component!

Comment: On Angular you have five ways to communicate between components, as described [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), depending on what you want to do and the relation of your components. Usually, parent-child is done with `@Input`, child-parent with `@Output` event emitter and between components that have no relation or more complex structure via a service. You can find more docs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/9454/component-interactions/29279/pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding#t=201707271355133757508)

Comment: could you help me out in my case as to how to get the filename property...the hero and child example from the above link seems to be quite not satisfying

Comment: I can take a look if you edit your question to add the first component code entirely and the relation between the components (the html code where you add the two)

Comment: have updated the question with code for component A (ButtonView) with its html and ComponentB code too....

Comment: is my code clear @BogdanC... do u need any more details?

Comment: The code as you have it now is working? If yes, put it on a plukr and I will try to fix it there.

Comment: I have updated the code necessary for my scenario... in plnkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/GI3EVFtqopy1WSktWxzf?p=preview  i doubt if u can get the UI and working code... im new to Plunkr :(

Comment: First you have to make it work on plunkr to be able to advance. At this point your plunkr could not load ng2-smart-tables dependency. Try to add it from the book icon on the right menu, then fix the app to work there.